# Cannot download zip files

Tags: proxy, 15.10, zip, android-studio, gradle

I cannot download from this link https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip in Firefox and Chrome in my Ubuntu 15.10. Actually, I faced this problem in Android Studio while opening a project. Android Studio was trying to download this zip file and failed. Then I tried it manually in my browsers and failed. I set proxy settings to no proxy in all areas, Android Studio, Firefox, and Chrome. Then I restarted all those, all in vain. I tried this link in Windows 7 and succeeded. What is going on? I cannot see anything but problems with OS, I dare say.

**Edit:**
wget result from terminal follows

[image]

Comment: No problems here. I am missing something in your question though: any errors? Did you try with "wget" from command line to see if the source errors out?

Comment: @Rinzwind check out edit.

Comment: `gradle-2.4-all.zip  100%[=====================>]  62,40M  11,9MB/s   in 5,7s `  ;-)

Comment: this work ? `wget http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip`

Comment: can you [edit] your post with the output of `ping downloads.gradle.org -c 5`

Comment: @Neil http worked, but I want https. how can i do that?

Comment: @ashubuntu You can use https right ? nothing blocking port 443, `sudo ufw allow 443/tcp`

Comment: bless you, my problem solved.

Comment: @ashubuntu i post it as an answer so port 443 was blocked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 443 is blocked, that's why you can't download files on https  connections.

Run this command to allow 443 on TCP :

```
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
```